# Affordable proof for Kirszbraun's theorem

Tags: continuity, hilbert-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I'm a third year student in the math program and I really like to explore interesting results about math, sometimes I think that I focus on things that are not even within my reach. I recently found a book on Lipschitz functions where I found a theorem called Kirszbraun's theorem which states the following: let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $f \colon A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a $L$-Lipschitz function, then there exists an extension $F \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ of $f$ which is also $L$-Lipschitz, that is, $F|_A =f$ and $L(F)=L(f)$.

Later they generalize this result for Hilbert spaces receiving the name of the Kirszbraun-Valentine theorem.

I had the audacity to start reading the proof in the case of Hilbert spaces, but there are really many things that I don't understand and that I haven't seen in the program yet. I studied many different proofs and some authors in their proofs use polytopes, others use filters, others use Kirszbraun Property (K), etc. I'm not really familiar with these concepts. Therefore, I would like to know if there is a more affordable proof for me, at least for the case in Euclidean spaces (I think that in this case the proof should be a little less rigorous). I would appreciate very much if someone can help me to get a more understandable proof for me.

I'm completely familiar with Lipschitz functions and it is very surprising to me that this type of extension is possible.

Comment: Probably you should define what exactly is a $L$-Lipschitz function and state some simple concrete examples? I like to think it is not something known to most people.

Comment: I don’t think Sampah’s suggestion is necessary. Encyclopedia of math seems to recommend *Geometric measure theory* by Federer (Springer), but I have no idea if it’ll fit you. Anyway, congratulations! Your curiosity has now led you towards tools and methods you’re not familiar with. It’s the *expected* outcome of doing math for real. In this case, it’s often worthwhile to at least look up the notions that one doesn’t know, and try and understand how they are used in the argument. Polytopes and filters are quite standard so it should be helpful knowledge anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed proofs in the lecture note of Krzysztof J. Ciosmak, and there are some small but harmless errors in the last part of the proof(the process of proving $g(y_0)\le 1$). However, the proof may include the concept like polytopes, because $y_0$ is in $\rm Conv{f(x_{i_{j}})}$.
[the lecture notes](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/Lecture%20notes%20-%20Extensions%20of%20functions.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You may find the result in chapter 7 of "Sets of Finite Perimeter" by  Maggi. He works in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$.